# Did the financial crisis affect the retirement patterns of Baby boomers?

Tags: financial-crises

Baby boomers are retiring and have been for a few years already. The financial crisis potentially made a large fraction f them change their retirement plans. Is there some measure / study of this effect? Are there any references to look at?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you'd find these specific references helpful to look at, but I hope it's a good start. Quandl has a database called [Social Security Administration](https://www.quandl.com/data/SOCSEC) and if you search "retirement" within the database, you will see datasets on number of retired recipients of social security, along with their spouses and dependents, and the average monthly amount they receive. Data goes back to the 1960s. Another database, [Federal Reserve Economic Data](https://www.quandl.com/data/FRED), also shows retirement data such as federal employee retirement plans and funds. Data goes to back to the 1940s. You'd have to search for "retirement" within the database. Both these databases are free to access. Hope this helps. [Disclosure: I work for Quandl]